# perform validations dynamically depending upon rules

Tags: c#, design-patterns, database-design

I am trying to design an HR leave application system. I need to know how best I can try to implement the following requirement in the front-end, as well as how to persist data in the db so that I can handle validations dynamically. Here is a small example of how we'd go about validating whether the employee is eligible for a leave.

Suppose he/she is applying for "sick leave" this type of leave cannot come directly next day to a "casual leave". One cannot apply for casual leave if the day previous to which he/she is applying for was marked for sick leave. Once we have validated this, we need to validate against leave balances. Suppose the employee is a programmer; he/she can take a max of 1 sick leave per month (or salary cycle). The number of sick leaves one can take in one month is dependent on the employee's designation.

The above was a simple example. The rules can go complex, and numerous depending upon the employee designation. I am looking at persisting such rules in the database.(what structure/attributes would I need for this) AND also evaluating the rules dynamically in front-end code (C#) (what design patterns do I need for this)

Answer (score 1):

[Rules Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) are ideal for complex business rules that can change frequently. Here's [a list for .Net.](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/rule-engines)

We use Drools (Java version) to process complex, ever-changing financial rules and it's been very successful for us.

Here's a good "getting started" tutorial

[Getting Started with Drools.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Drools_NETPrimer.aspx)

Here's the full user guide

[Drools.Net User Guide](http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/Drools.Net+-+3.0+User+and+Installation+Guide)

Comment: need some tutorial on how to use these engines.

Answer (score 1):

I recently read an article on Martin Fowler's site that talks about the "Specification" pattern.

Here is the link [Specification Pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf)

I think it could be suitable in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a system once where we had a set of rules let's say we defined 10 distant types of rules. Leave Balance would be 1 rule, for example. We then created a very simple expression tree and evaluated each node to determine if our condition passed. For example here is an AndRule which can be used to tie two operands together.

```
public Rule
{

   public abstract Eval(ContextData data);
}

public AndRule
{
    public Rule Left{get;set;}
    public Rule Right{get;set;}
    public override bool Eval(ContextData data)
    { 
       return Right.Eval(data) && Left.Eval(data);
    }
}
```

The next thing we did was enable the whole graph to be serialized to Xml. This allowed to persist the a clob of the rules to the database. The rules can be dynamically switched out by replacing the tree. Now yes you cannot dynamically create a new type of rule but I doubt your HR department is sitting around inventing new ways to limit days off (or maybe they are if you work for the PHB)